# Observable toPromise() get all data sent over next()

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, es6-promise

I have an observable (rxjs) that sends data using `subscriber.next(value)`.
How to get these data if the observable is converted to promise via the method `toPromise()`? Is that even possible? Or is it only possible to get the data passed through the complete method of the observable. 
Maybe there are options / methods in pipe, before converting to promise to get all data from `next()` as an array in the data field of the `then()` method of the promise.

```
getObservable().toPromise().then(data => {
  // data should contain all data sent from observable.next()
  console.log('Complete: ', data);
}, error => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

- **Current behavior** (expected but not wanted in this case): 
   
  `data` contains the data of observable.complete().
- **Wanted behavior**:
  `data` contains an array of all observable.next().
  This should enabled by an option or pipe.

Example with Observable.range():

```
let observer = Rx.Observable.range(1,5).toPromise().then(data => {
  console.log('Completed: ', data);
}, error => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

Output:

```
Completed: 5
```

Wanted:

```
Completed: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Is this using RxJS?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint. I added this tag. Using ionic and typescript. But no problem if native rxjs solutions are posted. :)

Comment: Before you convert to a promise, reduce all the values using https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reduce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html) before you make it a promise

```
const source = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
const example = source.reduce((acc,val) => acc.concat(val), []);

example.toPromise().then((data) => {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: You can also use the `source.pipe(toArray())` operator instead of having to manually reduce results into an array. Has the same results as above answer, just with less code.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> **Returns** (Promise): An ES2015 compliant promise which contains the last value from the Observable sequence. If the Observable sequence is in error, then the Promise will be in the rejected stage. If the sequence is empty, the Promise will not resolve.

So the returned promise will only resolve once the sequence has been completed, take the following code for example

```js
var source = new rxjs.Subject();

var promise = source.asObservable().toPromise();

promise.then(x => console.log(`Promise: ${x}`));

source.subscribe(x => console.log(`Observable ${x}`));

Array.of(1, 2, 3).forEach(i => source.next(i));

source.complete('Complete');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

As you see the `promise` resolves with the last emitted value, but **only after the sequence has been completed**.